# Using Flask, html page showing up blank

Tags: python, flask

So trying to finish a lab using Flask Templates

Here is my python code:

```
cryptosnapshots = (requests.get(f"https://api.finage.co.uk/snapshot/crypto?quotes=false&trades=true&symbols=&apikey=XXX")).json()

snapshot = (cryptosnapshots['lastTrades'][:20])

@app.route('/crypto_data', methods = ['GET']) # define the first route, the home route
def show_crypto(): # define the function that responds to the above route
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('show.html', snapshot = snapshot)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

and here is my the code from the html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
     {% for snapshot in snapshots %}
        <h2>Symbol: {{snapshot['s']}}</h2>
        <p> Last Price: {{snapshot['p']}}<p>
        
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

When python returns the url and I add my "/crypto_data" endpoint, the page just shows up blank...is my error on the python side or the html side (or is it the api??)?

TIA!

Im expecting the url and endpoint to lead to an html list of all the last trading price from the first 20 cryptos on the list.

My first issue was breaking down the API json and I thought once that was solved it would be a breeze...

labs due Sunday, someone help lol

Answer (score 0):

In the Jinja template, your are accessing a value name `snapshot`**`s`**. But in your Flask code, you are defininig a value name `snapshot`.

Try replacing the value named `snapshot` by `snapshots` in your Flask app:

```py
cryptosnapshots = (requests.get(f"https://api.finage.co.uk/snapshot/crypto?quotes=false&trades=true&symbols=&apikey=XXX")).json()

snapshot = (cryptosnapshots['lastTrades'][:20])

@app.route('/crypto_data', methods = ['GET']) # define the first route, the home route
def show_crypto(): # define the function that responds to the above route
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('show.html', snapshots = snapshot)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try saving your html file and then run python script again

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem. Consider taking the [tour].

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).